# Find min(records) and max(records)

Tags: sql

I have two tables as t1 and t2. t1 has M records, t2 has N records.
Both of these two tables doesn't contain any duplicate value. If I join both of these tables then, what would be the min(records) and max(records) in terms of M and N ?

**I was asked about this question few days back during an interview and I couldn't answer this. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Show the `join` statement.  It depends on how you join them.

Comment: Interviewer just gave me 1 hint that if I do a cross join then the result would be MxN records. I'm not sure how is it going to help here!

Comment: MxN is obviously the maximum value.

Comment: Hey! To become able to understand the reason the answer to this question is what it is, I'd suggest looking at what each of the different join types in SQL are, and how they combine the sets of the different tables. We could give you the exact answer, and likely someone will, but given that you're saying you couldn't derive the answer yourself, you'll likely learn interesting things by reading about different join types while thinking about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum records is `0` because whatever `join` conditions you use might always evaluate to true.

Assuming you are matching on "unique" ids (which I think is what you are trying to say by pointing out no duplicates), the maximum records is `n + m`, because you might use a `full join` between the tables, with no matching rows.

For an inner join, the maximum is `least(n, m)`.  All the rows in one table might match rows in the other -- but the non-matched rows won't be counted.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I understood why he gave me hint.

Comment: Could you please explain the min part bit more ? I'm getting little confused there.

Comment: @DexCode . . . If nothing matches, then an inner join returns no rows.